# Could you help me with the error of the white bar in the scroll?

Tags: html, css, version-control

I have a question and it is that in the SCSS, when I reach a dimension for mobile I get a white stripe on the right, I thought that the error was from the scroll but not since I removed it and it remains the same if someone could help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*first guess*  if you're using `vw`, `vh` in your CSS, and you're new to using them, the problem might come from them. change them to `%`...

---

open the Element tab of your developer tools.
For each element, you select (by a single click on them), delete them and see if the white space has gone or not.
if yes, you're one step closer to the source of your problem